# Cypher query: getting all information about Node with specific ID

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Im new in cypher queries and I try to return the persons who "PLAYED" a movie and the country where the movie was made
[image: Movies graph data]

Can someone help me to create a query ?

Comment: Maybe try going through the built-in tutorials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are looking for is to return the persons who "PLAYED" a movie and the country where the movie was made, you should try something like this:

```
MATCH (c:Country)<-[:MADE_IN]-(m:Movie)<-[:PLAYED]-(p:Person)
WHERE m.id = "movie_id"
RETURN p,c;
```

To avoid returning person duplicate you should use the distinct keyword: https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#return-unique-results

Answer (score 0):

If understand the question correctly, you want

```
 MATCH (n{id:"mySpecialId"})
 RETURN n
```

Comment: I changed it a little bit

Comment: Your question is now completely different - and even less clear. Please give a detailed example of what you want to achieve.